# Link to Google Play by redirecting and using User-Agent

Tags: android, google-play, user-agent

There are [two methods](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html) to link to the google play store:

From a web site:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

From an Android app:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

I already created a service that redirect to the appropriate link based on the user-agent:

```
    val baseURL = if (userAgentStr.toLowerCase().contains("android")) {
      "market://details?"
    } else {
      "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?"
    }
```

**My question**: Are their browsers that will have "android" in the user-agent that will not be able to interpret "market://" protocol?  Note, I am okay if some android devices go to the play-http-link.  However, the opposite is not acceptable.  (Non-android devices getting the market-link)

**Additional background:**
The problem with the play-store http link is that there is a prompt asking what app should open the app.  This prompt adds additional friction to the installation. (Its not the end of the world but its not ideal)  The market link works perfectly on Android devices but would 404 on other devices, which is not acceptable.